# what does a = b == c means in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I came across the below code and couldn't figure out what exactly happens here. I tried them on playground and able to manipulate the output but need help in understanding the code

```
myButton.isHidden = view.getButtonVisibleState() == false
```

Comment: Is this the total code? No if block or something similar wrapping it?

Comment: Operator == has precedence over =, so the statement eventually becomes - `myButton.isHidden = (view.getButtonVisibleState() == false)`. It seems you are new to programming. I would suggest operator precedence to study first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations. This is not specific to Swift, this is just a shorthand.

Comment: Equivalent: `myButton.isHidden = !view.getButtonVisibleState()`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking questions like this IMHO, and this is clearly written. Have an upvote.

Comment: Why is this downvoted. Guess the person who downvoted expects people to know everything before posting questions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Assignment operator (=) :**  It is used to assign the value to the left side variable.

**Equal to operator (==) :** It is used to compare two variables.

So for `a = b == c` means

First compare b & c, if they are equal then it returns **true** to `a` otherwise it returns **false** to `a`. That's how a is assigned the value.

**So for your issue `myButton.isHidden = myView.getButtonVisibleState() == false`**

you are assigning the value to myButton.isHidden as true or false.

So compiler first check if `myView.getButtonVisibleState()`is not visible then the statement `myView.getButtonVisibleState() == false` becomes **true** and assigns the `myButton.isHidden = true`

else `myButton.isHidden = false`

Answer (score 2):

equivalent to pseudo code:

```
if (view.getButtonVisibleState() == false) then
myButton.isHidden = true
else 
myButton.isHidden = false
```

You use the boolean value of the test and assign that to the variable directly to make the code shorter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you know the difference between *assignment* (`=`) and *relational is equal* (`==`).

It's time to get out your copy of the *operator precedence* table. On inserting the superfluous parentheses your statement becomes

`myButton.isHidden = (view.getButtonVisibleState() == false)`

So you can see that it sets `myButton.isHidden` to `true` if `view.getButtonVisibleState()` is `false`, and vice-versa.

In other words it's a simple toggle, and

`myButton.isHidden = !view.getButtonVisibleState()`

is probably clearer.